# What's the point of the Pilot's License?

Tags: endless-sky

In Endless Sky, what's the point of the pilot's license?

You are automatically given one at the beginning of the game. It shows up on the Outfitter screen with a cost of 50,000, but you can't sell the one you have or buy a new one (as far as I can tell.) The description just says that it's required by Republic law:

> For much of the Republic's nearly three century long history, being able to pilot your own starship was limited only by your ability to purchase one. But at the turn of the millennium in an attempt to increase tax revenue, the Republic Parliament passed a law requiring that all ship captains purchase a pilot's license, and for no small fee at that. Needless to say, this policy is not terribly popular with freelance merchant captains.

The [wiki](https://endless-sky.fandom.com/wiki/Pilot%27s_License?so=search) just reproduces the description text and notes that you start the game with it.

Is there a point to the license? Can you lose it somehow? I'm trying to figure out why it exists at all since it just seems to be "flavor" or a storytelling element. I found a [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/endlesssky/comments/3rrg33/can_someone_explain_the_concept_of_pilot_licenses/), but the answer was deleted. :(